# How to obtain integers from a txt file?

Tags: import

I have txt file with some comma-separated integers and i'd like to obtain a list of said integers to work with.

My best result was:

```
input = Import["Path/To/File","Data"];
intlist = StringSplit[input[[1]], ","];
```

But i don't like it, it feels hacky.

What is the best practice to do such task?

Also, what's the difference between `Import["Path/To/File","Data"];` and `Import["Path/To/File"];` in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `input = Import["Path/To/File", {"CSV", "Data"}];`

Comment: Hi @BobHanlon, that way we get the full content of the txt file as the first element of a list.

Something like ```{{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}}```

Comment: When the file only contains one line of data. then use `input = (Import["Path/To/File", {"CSV", "Data"} ]//First)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `"Data"` to your import statement means that Mathematica will try to interpret any numbers it sees as actual numbers. Without this it will usually import numbers as strings, and then you have to mess around with them to turn them into numbers.

In the case of a ".txt" file formatted like a CSV, you should be able to use

```
input = Import["Path/To/File.txt", "CSV"];
```

and end up with a matrix of numbers. Note that in your solution above, it might look like you have integers, but `Head[intlist[[1]]]` (or `Head[intlist[[1, 1]]]` if it's a 2D matrix) should yield `String`. Afterall, you use `StringSplit` to generate them.

Comment: Nice, but why do i get a list inside a list? I think that mathematica is interpreting the input as a 1-row matrix if that make sense.
Something like ```{{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}}```

Comment: @gabriel_q According to the documentation, CSVs are imported as a list of lists (i.e. a matrix). If you want a 1D list, you can always wrap it with `Flatten` --> `input = Flatten@Import["Path/To/File.txt", "CSV"];`.